# Hide keyboard when Edit Text in Recycler View is scrolled off screen

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` that contains `EditText` child elements. I would like to hide the soft keyboard when the selected `EditText` is scrolled off screen. How can I tell when the `EditText` is no longer on screen? Is there some event listener that I can attach to the `EditText` element to tell?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Implement `onTouchListener` like this:

```
yourRecycleView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I had to change edittext.getWindowToken() to v.getWindowToken() as the edit text is a private member of RecycleView Adapter. However, this worked well. Thank you.

Comment: How to remove highlighted warning saying about "perform click" is not override

Comment: Isn't this solution overkill for the application anytime you touch the view it throws an event?

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me : I used `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` with `PublishRelay` for debouncing events.

```
class RecyclerViewActivity : Activity(){
    ...
    private val scrollableRelay = PublishRelay.create<Unit>()
    private val disposable = CompositeDisposable()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                scrollableRelay.accept(Unit)
            }
        })
        scrollableRelay
            .debounce(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe({
                if (currentFocus == recyclerView) {
                    hideKeyboard()
                }
             })
            .addTo(disposable)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        disposable.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

Once the view is scrolled from the screen the focus goes up to recyclerView. 
So, we can implement this functionality using `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener`. 
`onScrolled` tracks even slightest scroll of the view. That's why we need to add `debounce` that we'll not receive a lot of events.

`hideKeyboard` and `addTo` are extension functions:

```
fun Disposable.addTo(compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable) {
    compositeDisposable.add(this)
}

fun Activity.hideKeyboard() =
    currentFocus?.let {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(it.windowToken, 0)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yourRecycleView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            edittext.clearFocus(); //hidden keyboard 
            return false;
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            if (!hasFocus) {
                handler.postDelayed(() -> {
                    if (!editText.hasFocus()) {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
                    }
                }, 200);

            }
        });
```

Comment: your solution shows the keyboard if I hide the keyboard before scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin solution that dismisses the keyboard when:

- the focused `View` is scrolled off the `RecyclerView`
- or if the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, and the OS was unable to find something to focus on that is inside the `RecyclerView`...

```
// dismiss the keyboard when it is no longer focusing on anything inside the recyclerview
recyclerView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalFocusChangeListener { _, newFocus: View? ->
    if (newFocus == recyclerView || recyclerView !in (newFocus?.ancestors ?: emptySequence())) {
        recyclerView.context.inputService.hideSoftInputFromWindow(recyclerView.windowToken, 0)
    }
}

val Context.inputService get() = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

val View.ancestors: Sequence<View> get() = generateSequence(this) { it.parent as? View }
```

Answer (score 0):

Been facing the same issue in `BottomSheet` . Took me a while to realize that to get `currentFocus` i have to use `dialog.currentFocus` instead of `activity.currentFocus` . Below is my Solution maybe it helps someone  .

```
binding.recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object:RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                dialog?.currentFocus?.let {
                    if(it is RecyclerView){
                        val imm = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                         imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(it.windowToken, 0)
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```